# What modifications do I need to make to this RegEx to allow lowercase letters only after a number is in the String?

Tags: regex

I have this RegEx:

```
^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

How can I modify this so that a lowercase letter can only appear in my string if there is a number and ONLY after that number?

These are expected matches:

```
AA
AB
1a
1b
1A
1B
A1A
A1a
AB1
AB2
AB1a
AB2b
```

These would fail:

```
Aa
Ab
a1
b1
Ab1
a1a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a positive lookbehind to assert that a digit must precede any lowercase letter:

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]|(?<=[0-9])[a-z])*$
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, a solution without a lookaround could be matching `[0-9][a-z]` and repeating the outer group 1 or more times to prevent matching an empty string.

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]|[0-9][a-z])+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z0-9]` Match either A-Z or 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9][a-z]` Match 0-9 and then a-z
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to prevent matching an empty string
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O1tKBh/1)